# Eclipse with IcedTea: use max memory

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, fedora, icedtea

I have a Fedora 16 System with 16GB of RAM.

> java version "1.6.0_22" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.4)
>   (fedora-60.1.10.4.fc16-i386) OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed
>   mode)

I try to launch eclipse using:

> eclipse/eclipse -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m

but it won't: "Failed to create Java Virtual Machine".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently trying to run Eclipse in a 32 bit JVM.  This is OK, but it means that you won't be able to use anywhere like all of your 16Gb of RAM.  The theoretical limit of what a Linux system will let a 32bit process use is less than 3Gb.

This doesn't explain why Eclipse is tanking when you ask for a 2Gb heap.  You should be able to allocate a bit more than that.  Have you checked Eclipse's log file to see if there is more information there?

Anyway, my advice would be to download and install a 64 bit JDK, and use that to run Eclipse.  If you decide to stick with 32 bit,  you ought to upgrade anyway because your current JDK is missing a number of important security fixes.